# Qt application interface freeze

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, exception, qtgui

I'm experiencing some problems with my embedded application. It is a page that contains a `QTimeEdit` that counts the time each second, some checkboxes and some `QLineEdit`s that refresh each second.

After some minutes of working, I see a freeze of interface, even if the application is still running. If a try to press buttons or checkboxes an access violation message appears:

> Exception 'Access Violation' (14): Thread-Id=05d80002(pth=8af6109c), Proc-Id=04a90002(pprc=91431714) 'nmb3.exe', VM-active=04a90002(pprc=91431714) 'nmb3.exe' PC=407ea307(qtgui4.dll+0x0005a307) RA=40d6c82c(qtgui4.dll+0x005dc82c) SP=01c1b928, BVA=00000004

The exception is related to `qtgui4.dll`. I checked if a saturation of virtual memory occurs, but this is not the problem that causes the freeze.

The freeze doesn't occur if I avoid to update the `QTimeEdit`, but I don't understand why.

Comment: can you share your code please?

Comment: The application is composed by a thread,mainwindow and a QWidget. The thread communicates with the QWidget by using signals/slots. Each second, it performs the following actions:                                 `time.start(); //QTime                                                                                                       emit updateTimeSignal(time);                                                                                                                             emit updateListOfSensorsSignal(sensorData); //update the different line edit instruments with sensors data`

Comment: Are you sure that you're updating the `QTimeEdit` in the GUI thread, and not some other thread?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. If i comment the emit to the QTimeEdit, it stops to show the incrementing time. In the same time I don't see the freeze of interface. Actually, the updateTimeSignal is the signal to a QWidget composed by a QtimeEdit and different labels

Comment: To be able to help you, we need your code to see how you coded it. It's possible that you have an access memory violation or a deadlock, but we can't figure out it if we don't see your code.

Answer (score 0):

You should move the timer into the mainwindow class, keeping the sensors handler in the separated thread.

The sensors handler should:

- store the data
- emit a "data ready" signal to the window

Then the timer in the mainwindow, every second, will:

- read the data from the sensors handler
- update the GUI

(make sure you are using thread-safe objects or, managing the critical sections)